# \alert beamer messes up tabular layout

Tags: tables, beamer

In `beamer`, I just want to highlight some cells with `\alert`, but when I use `\alert` it messes up my table layout. For some reason, I defined a special column type to have a more beautiful table. When I use `\alert` then it apparently messes up this layout and the cell falls out of place. I created a MWE that follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} 
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\alert{a} & b \\
c & d \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{L{1.3cm}L{1.3cm}}
\alert{a} & b \\
c & d \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody see a quick fix, so that I don't have to change my whole table and can still use `\alert` without killing the layout? That would make my life much easier.

Comment: I have the same problem. When I use `\alert{}` in a table then I get an extra white spave above the `alert`ed text. Does anyone know why? Because I also change the font formatting (`\bfseries` in my case), the proposed solution by @Werner doesn't work for me.

Comment: It seems to have something todo with the `\color{}`macro. Using `\textcolor{}` as suggested by @Werner though works for me.

Answer (score 5):

If it's just the colour change you're after, [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s `\alert` uses `red!95!black`. However, this is also stored in the colour `alert` or `beameralert`. Below I defined `\rawalert` which sets just the font colour using `\textcolor{beameralert}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\rawalert}{\textcolor{beameralert}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \alert{a} & b \\
    c & d \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{L{1.3cm}L{1.3cm}}
    \rawalert{a} & b \\
    c & d \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The mandatory argument will be captured by `\textcolor`. If you wish, you could use `\newcommand{\rawalert}[1]{\textcolor{beameralert}{#1}}`, but the outcome will be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that would fix the layout. On the other hand, I also liked to keep the possibility to overlay the highlights as it is possible with \alert<2>

    `\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{L{1.3cm}L{1.3cm}}
    \alert<2>{a} & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}`

Comment: @MaxM: An overlay-aware `\rawalert` is possible using this definition: `\newcommand<>{\rawalert}{\textcolor#1{beameralert}}`

Comment: I have the same problem. When I use `\alert{}` in a table then I get an extra white spave above the `alert`ed text. Does anyone know why? Because I also change the font formatting (`\bfseries` in my case), the proposed solution by @Werner doesn't work for me. Apart from that, the solution would work for me :).